# nested for loop for alphabet increment

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

I have searched everywhere and I cannot figure out how to create this output using a nested for loop in java:

"a

ab

abc

abcd"

continued until z

this is what I have tried

String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
    {
        for(char j = (char)(alphabet.charAt(i)); j<=i; j++)
        {

        System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Please help me!

Comment: Did you try anything? This is a really basic problem, so you should have been able to come up with something at least.

Comment: This shows not every the semblance of an attempt to actually write the code.

Comment: I will repost what I have tried so far. I get a blank output. @Absurd-Mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```java
for (int x = 'a'; x <= 'z'; x++) {   /* Loop from 'a' to 'z' */
    for (int i = 'a'; i<=x; i++){   /* Loop from 'a' to int x */
        System.out.print((char)i);
    }
    System.out.println(); /* New Line */
}
```

The outer loop switches from one row to another while the inner loop prints the characters (`'a'` to `x`)for that particular row.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go !

> print capital Alphabet

```
  public class Main
    {
  public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i, j;
        for(i = 1; i<=26; i++)  {
        for(j = 1; j <= 1-i; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        for(j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
        System.out.print((char)(char)(i+64)+" ");
        System.out.println(); //for line break
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry to hijack an answer, but there's no other way.  Please take more care when performing tag wiki excerpt edits.  You've added excerpts to tags with obvious typos, added dictionary definitions that were blatantly wrong (did not match the actual use of the tag), and worst of all, you're copying and pasting content from other sites without attribution.  If you aren't more careful, the system is going to end up blocking your ability to edit!

Comment: @Charles: Sorry about that. I have added many tags today, i agree some of them might be put with a wrong definition but i didn't do it intentionally. Next time i will be more careful. Thanks for acknowledgement that i am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

here you go!!

```
class nested_loop {
    void display () {
        char i,j;//i loop controls number of lines and j controls number of times in each line
        for(i='A';i<='E';i++) {
            {   
               for(j='A';j<='E';j++) {
                   System.out.print(j); 
               }
               System.out.println();//blank print statement takes control to the next line
            }
        }
    }
}
```