# Displaying characters in pattern from ASCII

Tags: javascript, ascii

Like what the title said, we wanted to display set of characters in a pattern from an ASCII value. We came up with this code but it doesn't work...

```
for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
            for (var j = 46; j < i + 1; j++) {
                document.write(String.fromCharCode(j));
            }
            document.write("<br>");
        }

        for(var k = 8; k > 1; k--) {
            for(var l = 97; l < k - 1; l++){
            document.write(String.fromCharCode(l));
            }
            document.write("<br>");
        }
```

The output should be like this:

A

AB

ABC

ABCD

ABCDE

ABCDEF

ABCDEFG

ABCDEFGH

ABCDEFGHI

abcdefgh

abcdefg

abcdef

abcde

abcd

abc

ab

a

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this exact question has been asked before, but I haven't been able to find it yet. However, I did find this [Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23206148/4200092) example, which is pretty similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            for (var j = 65; j < 65+i; j++) {
                document.write(String.fromCharCode(j));

            }
            document.write("<br>");
        }

        for(var k = 10; k > 1; k--) {

            for(var l = 97; l < 96+k; l++){

            document.write(String.fromCharCode(l));
            }
            document.write("<br>");
        }
```

Result:

```
A
AB
ABC
ABCD
ABCDE
ABCDEF
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFGH
ABCDEFGHI
abcdefghi
abcdefgh
abcdefg
abcdef
abcde
abcd
abc
ab
a
```